# yadcf undefined when filter option is selected

Tags: yadcf

I keep getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: yadcf is not defined" when selecting a filter option that was created using the yadcf.init method.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emLfa5s0/3/

var oTable;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    oTable = $('#test').DataTable({
        'retrieve': true,
        'paging':   true,  // Table pagination
        'ordering': true,  // Column ordering 
        'info':     true,  // Bottom left status text
        'bAutoWidth':     true,  // Bottom left status text
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "dom": 'lrtip',
         "oLanguage": {
            sLengthMenu:  '_MENU_ records per page',
            info:         'Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_',
            zeroRecords:  'Nothing found - sorry',
            infoEmpty:    'No results available',
            infoFiltered: '(filtered from _MAX_ total records)'
        },
         "deferRender": true
    });

    yadcf.init(oTable, [{
        column_number: 0,
        column_data_type: "html",
        filter_type: "multi_select"
    },{
        column_number: 1,
        filter_type: "multi_select"
    }], "footer");

});
```

STEPS TO RECREATE
1) The filters appear which demonstrate that yadcf was correctly initialized and that calling the init method did not *visibily* fail.  You can verify this by opening up the developer console and clicking the 'Run' button
2) When a filter value is selected the error referenced above appears in the console.

I was trying to quickly put together a shareable demo of a different issue I was experiencing but this error prevents me from getting there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include yadcf js file (and its css) using the *External Resources* of jsfiddle and not by dumping the entire code in the js/css panels

See [`working jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/emLfa5s0/6/) (b.t.w you better use chosen/select2 along with yadcf for a better looking UI)